# Custom type {fmt} formatters with external termplates, any drawbacks?

Tags: c++, fmt

I have a header that defines all {fmt} formatters for my custom types.

To improve compile times, I wanted to reduce the dependencies of this custom formatter header, and decided to define all formatters as external templates, where the implementation is put in a `.cpp`, with the declarations in the header file as follows:

```
template<>
struct formatter<MyType> : formatter<std::string>
{
  auto format(const MyType& t, format_context& ctx);
};

extern template struct formatter<MyType>;
```

...and the definitions in the `.cpp` file:

```
auto formatter<MyType>::format(const MyType& t, format_context& ctx)
{
  return format_to(ctx.out, "MyType: {}", ...);
}
```

The main advantage is that the header file becomes much less heavy, all custom types can be forward declared and I no longer include the world in case I want to have custom formatting of a single type within some translation unit.

However, most of the examples on implementing custom formatters with {fmt} define the `format()` function as a template function templatized on the `format_context` type:

```
template<typename FormatContext>
auto format(const MyType& t, FormatContext& ctx);
```

This does not really work with external templates since I would need to declare `format()` for all possible types of `FormatContext` up front. This is error prone. For now, only using `fmt::format_context` works and the compiler will tell me when it no longer suffices.

I would like to know what I lose by not having a format function templatized on the `FormatContext` type? In what situations is `fmt::format_context` not sufficient? Is there a better way to define these custom type formatters without having to put the complete implementation in header files? I was thinking about going the `std::ostream` route, and then simply including `<fmt/ostream.h>` whenever I would want to format my types with {fmt}, but it partially defeats the purpose of using {fmt} in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I loose by not having a format function templatized on the FormatContext type?

You'll lose the ability to format through an output iterator.
Previously this would mean that you won't be able to use
`format_to[_n]`. However in the current `master` this limitation has
been removed and both `format_to` and `format_to_n` work with
`format_context`. Now only [format string
compilation](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#compile-api) may require
custom output iterators.